# Pointer to C++ 2D Array

Tags: c++

I'm porting some C++ code to Actionscript 3 and just had a small question I'm confused about.

In one function, one of the parameters is  `int* myPtr`.  myPtr is the address of an element of a 2D-Array, `&my2DArray[x][y]`.  x and y are also parameters of the function.  I'm just a little bit confused with what is being accessed when the code accesses, for example, `myPtr[1]`. I think this would be the next element in `my2dArray`, but I'm not sure if this would be `my2DArray[x+1][y]` or `my2DArray[x][y+1]`.  Thanks for any help.

Additional info:
my2DArray is created by:

```
//initPtr is a int*, auxPtr is a int*, as is temp1
initPtr = (unsigned int *)NewPtr(
      sizeof(unsigned int) *
      X * Y);
  }

  auxPtr = initPtr ;

  for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    temp1 = auxPtr + i * Y;
    my2DArray[i] = (short *)temp1;
  } 

unsigned char* NewPtr(
  int size)
{
  return ((unsigned char*)calloc(size, sizeof(unsigned char)));
}
```

Comment: Be careful: initPtr is allocated as an array of unsigned ints, yet it is being accessed as shorts through my2DArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `my2DArray[x][y+1]`.  C++ uses row-major order for multidimensional array indices.  That means that large jumps in memory are changes in the left-most index, and single element jumps are changes in the right-most index.

Answer (score 0):

If myPtr truly is a pointer to an arbitrary cell in the array, then, unless you know the layout of the 2D array, you can't precisely. It is probably the next one in the row (assuming a standard C++ 2D array, but it might be down a row (if it were at the end of the row). Or, if the array is implemented as a 1D array of 1D arrays, then it might not even be a legal address (were it at the end of the row).